# Access to undeclared static property php fatal error

Tags: php

I am getting this error: `Access to undeclared static property: DBug::$errorMsg`

Following is the code

```
class DBug
{
    private static $errorMsg = array(
        1 => 'inv-req',
        2 => 'inv-reqPrm',
        3 => 'no-set',
        4 => 'less-h',
        5 => 'less-w'
    );

    public static function showTinyErrMsg($errCode=0) 
    {
        if(SHOW_ERROR_MSG_IN_RESPONSE === TRUE) {
            if(array_key_exists($errCode, self::$errorMsg)) {
            echo "// ".self::$errMsg[$errCode].";\n" ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I call this function by `DBug::showTinyErrMsg(1);`. I get the above mentioned error. I am surely missing some OO rule, please help me with this.

P.s: The reason for this class having all static member is, that it's a long standing class with all static members, so I had to add this new method as static

Comment: As an aside, perhaps either you should add to the array the error code 0, or perhaps  not have a default value for it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The property is `$errorMsg`, but you're calling `$errMsg`.

Comment: Ohh my god....so horrible of me, sorry for posting such terrible question. You can't imagine, I cracked my head for half an hour and it came to be this silly-a** mistake. Thanks a lot

Comment: Bit strange though, that the error message refers to DBug::$errorMsg being unknown.

Comment: yeah, then error should have been about errMsg. Yeah that also mislead me and I overlook that spelling mistake.

Comment: No idea why I keep getting upvotes for this. Surely this very particular problem can't befall so many people unable to spot it?

Comment: worked for my problem too. That error was strange, found in some MIME Type Library. @Utkanos thanks for your solution!